# html php passing a variable through multiple pages and inside forms

Tags: php, html, mysql, http-headers

Page 1:

```
<label for='name'>Name:</label>
<input type='varchar' name='name' maxlength="30" required />
```

Page 2: (processing which page to move to using headers)

```
$name = $_POST['name']
....
header('Location: page3.php?name=$name');
```

Page 3:

```
<form id='whatever' action="page4.php" method='post'>

    <?php

    $sql = "select * from table";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
       echo '<option value="' . $row["data1"] . '">' . $row["data2"] . '</option>;
    }
    ?>
<input type="submit" name="submitform" value="submit">
```

So as you can see here, in page 3 when I submit the form I get the data1 value into page 4. However, no matter where I declare my $_GET on the 'name' variable I can't get it through to page 4.

Page 4 is where I insert the data into the databases.

Comment: Why not use sessions.

Comment: `<input type='varchar'` is that a valid type? has html adopted mysql?

Comment: @Dagon You already know that answer ;=)

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes i annoy people with this approach all the time

Comment: @Dagon The more the merrier.

Comment: Haha woops. I don't have any experience with session so I wouldn't even know where to start.

Comment: You are using the wrong kind of quotes, variables don't get expanded when you use single quotes, you need double ones.

Comment: that mary, has loose morals

Comment: @Dagon Although; the `type='varchar'` concept idea isn't a bad one neither. It may very well end up on somebody's "to do" plate one day. *Rather interesting*.

Comment: its like textarea's brother

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['post_name'] = $name; // after cleaning $name ofcourse, validate, filter, validate.
```

On the next page:

```
session_start();
$var = $_SESSION['post_name'];

// do your validate, filter validate then on with the rest of its usage.
```

Just remember if you destroy the session before its grabbed you will lose it.

Comment: So I'll just put that on the top of the first page right?

`<?php 
session_start()
?>`

Comment: If you are going to go the sessions route then i personally prefer to have require_once a file that contains all my session related information (basically anything that i put into the session for use across multiple pages. but yes, that line in the top of your php file will start a session for you and update it and access it as shown above.

Comment: Ok let's say I do that. My page3 is still a giant form, how can I pass more than one variable to the fourth page?

Comment: if page 3 is a form in itself, then start the session on page 3 at the top. pull any data and sanitize it then apply it to the form.

Once that form is "posted" to page 4 gather it with $_POST as you have already.

Comment: it does look like you are complicating the form process but if you need separate pages and continuous data passing then you will want to update the session on each page that can collect post data and then pull everything together, session and post on the last page.

There is another option, and that is to not submit anything at all, use javascript to load each section of the form and hide it until the full form is ready to be sumbitted

Comment: The problem I'm having is my form has a drop down box that pulls information from the database, so I can't declare the <?php?> at the top?...

Comment: You can declare it anywhere you like inside the php file. at the top <?php //do something ?> then in a form the same again or you can just open php at the beginning and with correct encapsulation you can actually print the form out via php.

If i was you i would look for some online PHP tutorials before you continue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73702/discussion-between-chris-and-user2963379).